# Geodesic action under push forward

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $g$ be a metric on a manifold $M$.
Suppose we have a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$.
How can I prove that the equality 
$$\int_{[0, 1]} g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))dt=\int_{[0, 1]} g_{\phi (\gamma(t))}(\phi_*\gamma'(t), \phi_*\gamma'(t))dt$$

holds? Here $\phi_*\gamma'(t)$ denotes the pushforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need in addition that $\phi$ is an isometry for this to be true. Here is a counterexample when $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism that is no isometry. Consider the half-plane
$$
\mathbb{H}=\{(x,y):y>0\}
$$
with metric 
$$
g=\frac{1}{y^{2}}\left(dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy\right).
$$
Let $\gamma$ be the curve defined by
$$
\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}:t\mapsto (t,2)
$$
and take for $\phi$ the map
$$
\phi:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}:(x,y)\mapsto(x,y^{2}).
$$
Note that the pushforward $\phi_{*}$ satisfies $\phi_{*}(\partial_{x})=\partial_{x}$. Then on one hand,
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))dt&=\int_{[0,1]}g_{(t,2)}(\partial_{x},\partial_{x})dt=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{4}dt=\frac{1}{4},
\end{align}
whereas
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}g_{\phi(\gamma(t))}(\phi_{*}\gamma'(t),\phi_{*}\gamma'(t))dt=\int_{[0,1]}g_{(t,4)}(\partial_{x},\partial_{x})dt=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{16}dt=\frac{1}{16}.
\end{align}

Comment: i was in doubt because  of the response of this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248863/diffeomorphism-invariance-and-geodesic-action

Comment: @amiltonmoreira The claim there is wrong. See for instance this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764018/proof-verification-diffeomorphism-is-an-isometry-if-and-only-if-it-preserves-th?rq=1 The proof given there can be adapted to show that a diffeomorphism $\phi$ is an isometry if and only if the equality you wanted to prove holds for all curves $\gamma$.